# Select printer tray

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, printing

I have a Question about printing files via a Socket Connection.

Here is m Simple Code so send a file via socket to a IP Printer ->

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
clientSocket.NoDelay = true;

IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.192.6");
IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(ip, 9100);
clientSocket.Connect(ipep);

byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("test.txt");

clientSocket.Send(fileBytes);
clientSocket.Close();
```

The Problem:

We need to print invoices on a different paper. This paper is on the second printer tray.
Example:

```
IP1 need to print on tray 1
IP2 need to print on tray 3
```

Is there a option so send a file via socket connection to print a file on the second printer tray?

Comment: I would say "Yes" there is probably a way to do that. Maybe an easier way would be to set those trays as default for the printers

Comment: Hi, yes but i need to print on different trays with my service :/ Invoice XYZ to tray 1 Invoice XYZ1 to tray 2